# How do i host a website on Ubuntu-server?

Tags: ubuntu, web-hosting, ubuntu-server

Im lost in the start, middle and end of this process. I cannot find a proper tutorial of how to make a functional server while owing a domain and using a vps for hosting. What else would I need, and how do i go about this.
Thanks All,
Ayden

Answer (score 0):

Usually the workflow to host your website involves completing the following steps (not necessarily in this order tho):

- Buy a domain name
- Buy somewhere to host the website
- Link the domain to the host by adding the nameservers/DNS entries into the domain admin panel pointing to the hosting IP
- Set a strong password on the root user and ensure all user on your machine are password-less protected through SSH keys, also disable password auth entierely (avoids lot of issues)
- Setup a fail2ban + firewall so that someone trying to bruteforce will be banned
- Setup some sort of reverse proxy (Apache, NGinx, HAProxy and so on) to proxy request from the outside to your application in a safe, efficient and controllable way
- (if you expect large volume of requests/s): setup docker/kubernetes/swarm/anything that allows you to make use of the load-balancing feature of your prefered reverse proxy
- Configure the reverse proxy to map each domain/path to the related service in your architecture
- Configure SSL certificates for FREE with LetsEncrypt (certbot) or ZeroSSL and enjoy your users navigating with security on your website (and avoid them being MiTM'ed)
- Configure some UptimeRobot/Checkly/Statuspage so you know when shit happens and can react in a timely way
- Enable mail forwarding on your domain name admin panel so that `admin@domain.tld`, `webmaster@domain.tld`, `hostmaster@domain.tld`, `contact@domain.tld`, `{ceoname}@domain.tld`, `no-reply@domain.tld` and so on points to valid email addresses

I'm probably forgetting some tasks, but of them should be straghtforward if you Google/DuckDuckGo the keywords next to them ;)

Kind regards,
William